# What's the antonym of VPL?

Tags: lang, mit-scratch

VPL means VisualProgramingLanguage(such as [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/) by MIT.). 
But I don't know antonym of VPL.
Doesn't use blocks language. E.g., JavaScript, Ruby, Python, C.

Could you tell me?

Comment: Personally, I find the whole categorization rather superficial. Under the hood, Scratch is still text (JSON). The cutie-pie editor on top of it cannot hide the fact that it's just a humdrum imperative language. MIT could have opted to write a 'visual' editor for Python instead. Would that suddenly place Python in a different category of languages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, text-based source code languages like JavaScript are the non-visual programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an antonym per se (Well, unless you consider "text-based programming languages"), however, anything that is not a Visual Programming Language can be classified in [other categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type).

JavaScript, Ruby, Python and C are [General-purpose Programming Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_programming_language).